# Why do I get "partition values: [empty row]" log messages when reading a file?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using Spark SQL to read in a csv, I also get a lot of such messages:

```
...some.csv, range: 20971520-24311915, partition values: [empty row]
```

Why does it say it's empty row? Is the partition real empty?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Neither the file nor the Spark partition with data read from the file is empty.

The log message may be a bit confusing because of two things:

- The word *partition* in the message refers to a *Hive-style partition*, i.e. a named partition column that can have multiple values. Such partitions can be [inferred from your directory structure](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/8ff8e16e2da4aa5457e4b1e5d575bd1a3a1f0358/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/PartitioningUtils.scala#L70), e.g. for `/path/to/partition/a=1/b=hello/c=3.14` they would be `a`, `b` and `c`, and their values: `1`, `hello` and `3.14`. They can also [come from the Hive Metastore](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/4dfd746de3f4346ed0c2191f8523a7e6cc9f064d/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/CatalogFileIndex.scala#L110) in case of partitioned external tables.
- The *partition values* logged are [wrapped in an `InternalRow`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/ccc4a20453bbbaf1f3e5e46fb7c0277f1e6c65b9/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/FileScanRDD.scala#L46), not in a collection.

In your case, the directory structure is flat or it does not contain partition names (e.g. `/path/to/partition/1/hello/3.14`), so there are no Hive-style partitions and you see `[empty row]` in the message as a result.