# pyspark message during re-partition: partition values: [empty row]

Tags: pyspark

All
I am using pyspark to compact small files, but get a lot of messages of following type:

```
23/10/03 10:40:44 INFO FileScanRDD: Reading File path: hdfs://ccycloud-1.mr-x.root.hwx.site:8020/user/mrostron/gen/gen-2023100219-csv/gen-20231002195101.csv, range: 0-2696074, partition values: [empty row]
```

from reading another case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47542947/why-do-i-get-partition-values-empty-row-log-messages-when-reading-a-file), the message results from directory not containing partitioning segments (/p1=v1/p2=v2/ etc) - i am guessing the method is intended only for hive-style partitioned tables.

in any case, the compaction works, but the message is annoying. So, is there any way i can avoid the message (maybe disable the check which generates the message) ?

the code is:

```
# 2 arguments
# - input_directory
# - outputdirectory
import sys
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
if len(sys.argv) != 3:
  raise Exception("bad command line arguments %s" % (sys.argv) )
input_directory  = sys.argv[1]
output_directory = sys.argv[2]
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
print( "Starting collect.py with args %s" % (sys.argv) )
print("COMPACTION:input_directory:%s:output_directory:%s" % (input_directory,output_directory))
df  = spark.read.csv(input_directory)
cnt_before_compaction = df.count()
print("INPUT DATAFRAME:rowcount:%d" % cnt_before_compaction)
df.repartition(1).write.mode("overwrite").format("csv").save(output_directory)
df1 = spark.read.csv(output_directory)
cnt_after_compaction  = df1.count()
print("OUTPUT DATAFRAME:rowcount:%d" % (cnt_after_compaction))
print("End Success")
```

Thanks v much for any guidance on this, mr

Answer (score 0):

you can set the logging to a higher level like WARN or ERROR in your code :

```
import logging  # Import the logging module

logging.getLogger("py4j").setLevel(logging.WARN)
```